# After fork a repository I should clone the project from the original repo or my repo?

Tags: git, github

After fork a repository from github, it will create a new repository for myself, but when cloning that repository, I should do it from where? The original repository or my repository? What is the difference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683596/should-i-fork-and-clone-my-repository-or-just-clone-the-original

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you want to do. Once you fork a repository, your fork might be ahead or behind the original one. If the original repository has changed, you won't get those changes unless you manually sync your fork. The opposite is also true - if you introduce changes to your fork, and you want to contribute to the original repository, you should submit a PR to sync it with your changes.

Now you should ask yourself which "version" you want to have - the one that includes your changes that are not yet synced with the original repository, or you want the most updated version of the original repository.

Comment: The difference is not very significant because whichever you first clone from, you can always add the other repository -- the original or the fork -- as an additional remote with `git remote add [REPOSITORY-URL]`. Then you can push or pull branches to either repository by mentioning the repository name on the command line.